# Can not read plist from mainbundle

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, plist

I am having some strange problem.

I cant read plist file from application mainbundle

the file is in the "copy bundle resource"

but somehow it can not be read

here is the code

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"8chk" ofType:@"plist"]);
```

it prints (null) all the time

here is the screenshot

[image]

can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: You can't get the path or you can't read the file contents?

Comment: i cant read the file path, i cant read the file contents..

Comment: What are the 3 errors in your screenshot?

Comment: errors are not related. they are gone now

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid to say that , you are not adding this `8chk.plist` to your target.

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop plist file again in project, make sure you tick on checkbox while adding file to project which is saying "copy file in ProjectName"

then use this code to make it accessible and read values from plist

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"YourPLIST" ofType: @"plist"]; 
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];
[id obj = [dict objectForKey: @"YourKey"];
```

OR

```
// Reads the value of the custom key you added to the Info.plist
NSString *value = [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"key"];

//Log the value
NSLog(@"Value = %@", value);
```

Comment: 8 chak k bhai yeh check kro

Comment: please reply in english. I am not pakistani

Comment: delete your plist file from project then add it again

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Info.plist"];
```

This might work. make sure to copy the plist to target and put it in root directory.also u can try to put the plist files where the apps default plist is kept.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Shoeb Amin please check your plist file is add inside Target->Copy Bundle resource

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong. `copy bundle resource` should read just `8chk.plist`, not `8chk.plist ..in resources/8chk` if the project navigator shows the correct tree.